# VSC Extension: Set the language of a document?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to programatically update the language of an open document, as part of an extension.

`TextDocument.languageId` allows me to read this as string (read-only) but what can I call to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
setTextDocumentLanguage(document: TextDocument, languageId: string): Thenable<TextDocument>
```

> Set (and change) the language that is associated with the given document.
>
> Note that calling this function will trigger the onDidCloseTextDocument event followed by the onDidOpenTextDocument event.

source: [api](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#languages)